# EntityFieldQuery for getting the count of a user blog

Tags: 7, database

EntityFieldQuery for getting the count of a user blog. Blog is a content type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
global $user;

$query = new EntityFieldQuery;

$count = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
 ->entityCondition('bundle', 'blog')
 ->propertyCondition('status', 1) // Getting published nodes only.
 ->propertyCondition('uid', $uid)
 ->count()
 ->execute();

print $count . ' blogs from ' . $user->name;
```

Comment: Hint: use constant NODE_PUBLISHED instead of 1. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/constant/NODE_PUBLISHED/7